# PHP and NGINX on CentOS

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am using NGINX with PHP 5.4.23 on CentOS

I am facing very wired issue on it.

when i see phpinfo(), it says

```
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php.ini
```

but when i do changes in this file, it don't shows in phpinfo().

I also restarted nginx and check it. but not changes reflected.

Comment: You should restart php-fpm instead of nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to restart php-fpm service :

```
service php-fpm restart
service php5-fpm restart //if you avec php5
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart //if you avec php5
```

EDIT :

you have php-fastcgi, so replace ftpm by fastcgi :

```
/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi restart
```

Comment: when i dont have **php-fpm** or **php5-fpm** in **init.d**, I have **php-fastcgi**

Comment: when I restart it says **/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi: line 44: configtest: command not found**. when I start it it dont shows anything. when I tried to stop it says **Stopping php-cgi:                                          [FAILED]**

Comment: try to remove the line :

configtest || return $?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/php-fastcgi status`
then killed that process [`kill -9  pid`]